# Vue.js - wait until animation finishes before updating a component

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, vue.js, vuejs2

My page is a mix of static HTML+JQuery and some parts are written in Vue.js.

I have a simple Vue counter component that observes an array from a reactive store and shows the length of the array.

I also have a button on that adds something to the store's array. Currently, when the button is clicked, the counter immediately refreshes.

I want now to implement an animation (probably using JQuery) that runs for about a second when the button is clicked and I want the refresh of the counter to be deferred until the animation finishes. However, I can't just delay the insertion to the array, because I have other Vue components that observe it as well and I want them to update immediately. I also have another button that removes from the array and I want decreases to be applied immediately on the counter.

Can you suggest how to implement it using Vue.je?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shadow array that the counter observes. `watch` the source array, and use `setTimeout` to copy it to the shadow array after a delay.

Comment: I edited the question - forgot to mention that I also have a decrease button and I want decreases to be applied immediately. But maybe I could have a watcher that checks a flag and decides whether to copy immediately or with a delay. Then I can set the flag only when the animation is fired. Is it what you suggest?

Comment: That sounds reasonable.

Comment: One last question, where should the flag live? I'd like to avoid a simple global. It could live in the counter, but then the button needs to reference the counter directly, which seems to be discouraged by the community.

Comment: It should live in the common ancestor of the button and the counter, and be passed to each of them (the button would emit events to get the parent to change the value). Or you could use a bus.